# My CSS works in dev tools, but not after I apply it - what I am doing wrong?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to change the background color of .notebox element on category page in dark mode. Here's my code:

```
body.wp-night-mode-on .category .notebox {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

The thing is, it doesn't work when I apply the changes. It works in dev tools tho.

What mistake I am making? Here's an example page with that element (category description, just above post list - please turn on dark mode in the bottom right corner to see what I mean):

Comment: category class is in body tag. so try `body.wp-night-mode-on.category .notebox` and this will work

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use `body`. The below is sufficient.

```
.wp-night-mode-on .category .notebox {
```

or

```
body .wp-night-mode-on .category .notebox {
```